# Transform views rather than projectors reduces performance with respect to C-style approach in checking if two strings are case-insensitively equal

Tags: c++, performance, c++20, benchmarking, range-v3

##### tl;dr

In checking if two strings are case-insensitively equal, why is this code

```cpp
bool rangeV3WithTransformViews(std::string_view str1, std::string_view str2) {
    return equal(str1 | transform(tolowercase),
                 str2 | transform(tolowercase));
}
```

that much slower than this?

```cpp
bool rangeV3WithProj(std::string_view str1, std::string_view str2) {
    return equal(str1, str2, std::equal_to{}, tolowercase, tolowercase);
}
```

From the latter code, GCC 13.2 with `-O3` manages to generate the same assembly code as the low level C-style solution:

```cpp
#define to_lower_ascii(c) (((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z') ? (c) + 32 : (c))

int cstyle(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    while (*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0' && to_lower_ascii(*str1) == to_lower_ascii(*str2)) {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return to_lower_ascii(*str1) - to_lower_ascii(*str2);
}
```

#### More datails

The origin of my question is my sense of frustration when I realized such a verbose, low-lever, and unreadable¹ code is written to make such a simple thing as a case-insensitive string equality.

So I started writing out a range-based solution. Initially I ended up with the first solution above, thinking it was the best I could write, but [quick-bench.com proved me wrong](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/Qbhmt-y6J5KOQ2hiR86qNo2yLfs). Yes, maybe I haven't written the test carefully and haven't read the documentation of Google Benchmark, but two things are clear

1. GCC (at least the version on QuickBench, and with those options) manages to compile `rangeV3WithProj` down to the same assembly as `cstyle`, which means that the compiler could 100% see through the abstractions;
2. `rangeV3WithProj` is simpler than `rangeV3WithTransformViews` and uses less abstractions, so I don't see any reason to think that the former can be slower than the latter.

I would expect that the compiler could see through `rangeV3WithTransformViews` too, though, and generate the same assembly code, but it doesn't.

So my questions are:

- What, if anything, makes the first snippet inherently slower than the second?
- What, if anything, makes harder for the compiler to work out the same assembly for the first snippet as for the second and third?

I think the problem is with `transform`, which is the only difference between `rangeV3WithTransformViews` and `rangeV3WithProj`, but why does it have the effect it has (different assembly, and maybe worse performance)? After all, the size of `str1` and `str2` is known in the function in O(1), because they're `std::string_view`s, hence they satisfy [`sized_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/sized_range), and `transform` gives back a `sized_range` for `sized_range` inputs, so it's not like there's a loop of uknown length or anything like that, no?

##### Caveat

I don't really know what QuickBench does, but one thing that makes me nervous is that Compiler Explorer doesn't generate correspondigly identical assembly codes [for `rangeV3WithProj`](https://godbolt.org/z/eYrscaKca) and [for `cstyle`](https://godbolt.org/z/6e7qqaYca), even though I pass `-O3 -std=c++20` just like on QuickBench.

---

(¹) Would have you noticed, if I had bugged the code by changing some `!=` to  `==`, `32` to `34`, the last `str2` should be `str1`, or something similar?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256760/discussion-on-question-by-enlico-transform-views-rather-than-projectors-reduces); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your benchmark is wrong.

If you enable the "no-op" bar, you'll find that `rangeV3WithProj` and `cstyle` are ~1× as fast as doing literally nothing: They are optimized out.

You actually want to make sure `b` is not optimized out, not a function pointer: `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);` instead of `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(<function name>);`.

Even then, the timing is still unfair because `rangeV3WithProj` and `rangeV3WithTransformViews` have to call `std::tolower`, which has to look at the current locale. To be fair, use `std::tolower` with all three or use your macro for all of them with `constexpr auto tolowercase = [](char c)->char{ return to_lower_ascii(c); };` (to ensure that all functions have the same result).

Also, your third function is slightly different: It requires a nul-terminated C-string instead of a sized contiguous range of characters. You also have to use `!cstyle(str1, str2)` it to get the same result. You *can* use ranges algorithms with nul-terminated C-strings, but not out of the box (https://godbolt.org/z/TKfM5Ph4o)

---

With `std::ranges`, the two methods with ranges compile to the exact same assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/GbTcKTP4x

The same with Range-v3: https://godbolt.org/z/Th4oT8f7c (though it is slightly different from the `std::ranges` assembly)

Given that the exact same code is generated, there should not be a difference in runtime.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the `DoNotOptimze` calls :( Thanks for pointing that out! And thanks for the iterator to make C-strings ranges. Do you have an opinion as to why neither version compiles to the same code as the C-style code? `ranges::equal` looks so simple, but even so, literally substituting its body in the code (and removing the redundant `constexpr`, substituting the arguments for the parameters' names [results in different assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/7qsYaGfxr). Do you know why is that? Am I committing another gross mistake? :D